# How do I change the background of my UISearchbar search field in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

How do I change the background of my searchfield? It is set to white now which makes it invisible to the user.

[current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU7Bj.jpg)

This is my code:

```swift
     //CHANGE COLOR OF NAVIGATION BAR
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    //SEARCH FIELD
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self as? UISearchBarDelegate


    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 44)
    let titleView = UIView(frame: frame)
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchController.searchBar.frame = frame
    titleView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    }
```

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood, what do you want exactly ?

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple. You just need to add this line :

```
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .gray //You can set whichever color you want here
```

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood, what do you want exactly ?